# jQuery UI put items into other containers

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I search a good way to put `<li>` entrys into other `<ul>` container.
The clue is, that when the `<li>` element is dropped into it's origin `<ul>` it should be reverted to it's origin place. I do not want them to be sortable.
When it is droppen on an other list, it should be added to that `<ul>`.

I am using the sortable plugin with the "connectWith:" option, but it does not work how I want.

Do you have some ideas, how it could work?
Or whitch plugin is better for that idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to maintain some metadata about original positioning using attrs on your li or the [jquery .data()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data#namevalue) method and then resort the list "manually" when the drop event fires:

```
$('.selector').droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the draggable and droppable utilities instead of the sortable?